# Clean up the [site-recommendation] meta tag

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request, meta

The [site-recommendation](/questions/tagged/site-recommendation) meta tag is about the entire Stack Exchange network, not about Stack Overflow specifically. The excerpt says:

> Don't know where to ask your question on the Stack Exchange Network? Give as much detail as possible about the question you'd like to ask, and the community will help you find the appropriate site.

The wiki text for the tag was created from (I assume) a copy-and-paste from the newly created MSE site.

There are currently 253 questions with the tag, most of which were created after the MSO-MSE split.

What should we do with the tag and the questions? Should we fix the wiki tag, or remove the tag altogether?

Comment: What you're really asking is whether or not we should allow such questions here.

Comment: True, [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234530/where-should-i-ask-about-experience-outside-of-the-workplace-as-it-pertains-to-i) came up recently, and it makes no sense that MSO should handle anything outside the scope of StackOverflow. That's why we had the split.

Comment: I personally think that all such requests should go to meta.stackexchange.com, but I know there will be folks that ask "My question was closed on Stack Overflow.  Where should I ask it?"

Comment: @RobertHarvey FWIW similar tag seems to be considered okay at P.SE meta: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/site-rec

Comment: @gnat: I'm not overly concerned either way.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not convinced we need to clean-up the history. I skimmed over those 253 questions and all seem to be bound by the scope defined in the wiki:

> Site recommendation questions on Meta Stack Overflow should be related to programming or computing. If you want to ask about a question dealing with a different topic (e.g., home improvement, politics, pure mathematics, etc.), your question should go on https://meta.stackexchange.com instead.

Now that scope was added in 2015, nearly a year after you asked your question.

I have written a lengthy answer on [Should site-recommendations be on topic for MSO or be asked on MSE?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370612) to advocate that the tag is on-topic.

At best those 250 questions have a couple of duplicates that are not closed against a proper canonical. I don't think we need an organized mob to clean that tag nor does the tag need to meet trogdor.  This is fine.

The tag can be handled under normal moderation. There is no coordinated effort needed to make that tag and their questions behave.