# Where best to ask this question on Stack Exchange, if at all?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33574155/notable-electronic-systems-that-dont-have-a-cpu-or-other-programmable-part) on Stack Overflow, but it's probably off-topic.

After discussing it in [SO Close Vote Reviewers chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/26730378#26730378), it was suggested to ask here, with the 'site-recommendation' tag. Which (if any) is the best Stack Exchange site, to ask this question?

Comment: You should be asking on meta.stackexchange.com, not meta.stackoverflow.com, since you know its not on topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I don't think there would be any good place to ask a question like that in the stackexchange network.

Comment: Asking for list of things, especially for pure entertainment without any practical purpose  is unlikely to be on-topic on any SE sites.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Except a meta site ;)

Comment: @Servy I have had similar discussions before but wouldn't this meta be the first stop for SO users, instead of sending them off to a new site (MSE). If your statement is true, shouldn't we burninate and blacklist [meta-tag:site-recommendation], as proposed by one of the SOCVR room owners [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261454/clean-up-the-site-recomendations-meta-tag)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov except it's not simply entertainment. It will educate me, and other readers. That may not qualify it for SE (which prefers Q/A questions, I know), but lets not make out that these types of question serve only to entertain.

Comment: @tom Can you give the link to transcript for the discussion (instead of the room link directly) Thanks.

Comment: @BhargavRao discussion starts here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/26729971#26729971

Comment: How will having this knowledge help someone though? I can't seem to see any value to it other than trivia.

Comment: You should ask Watson.

Comment: @JoeW It could broaden the horizons of an engineer. Given the prevalence of CPUs, I can imagine a young engineering grad believing that the only way to build a control system is to start with a programmable device (CPU), and then write some code/logic against it. I believe that 'knowing how the world around you works' is valuable context for an engineer. But maybe it's just me. If you and others see no value in that then maybe I'm the odd one out.

Comment: Last time I checked there was still lots of technology around that fits the bill of what you are asking. Also I don't think that engineering grads are going to forget all the amazing things that have been created in the past.

Comment: The format of that question is structured more like the ones at http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/

Comment: May be worth mentioning that Jeff himself tweeted this question!  https://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/662843613215256577?s=09

Comment: why did you ask this if you are not going to accept the answer **Nowhere**. It seems no matter what anyone or how many people say it, you do not want to hear anything but what you want to hear. This is a trivia question **at best**! And I would argue that it is so poorly phrased that it is completely opinion based because of the lack of specificity. So why did you ask this if you want argue with every single person that does not tell you what you want to hear?

Comment: [confused]. I did accept an answer that is 'nowhere'.

Comment: Please add a screenshot of the question, otherwise only high reputation users can see it since it's deleted.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It doesn't belong anywhere on SE, because SE is for questions for which a single definitive answer exists. This question is essentially a poll / 'list building question' - i.e. multiple answers would be required to answer the question fully.

Comment: The sub sites: 'Code Golf and Puzzels' as well as 'World Building' consist mostly of collective answer lists... I think your question was a good one => +1 :).

Comment: if you google *"define trivia"* it returns ***trivia: details, considerations, or pieces of information of little importance or value.*** Semantically exactly what the list building question is exactly. Regardless of how you *feel* something is does not change the semantic definition or the reality. The question that is now deleted fits this definition exactly.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Your edit to my answer makes it cleaner - thanks. IMO,  whether something is 'important' or 'of value', is a *value judgement* (as previously stated in my answer). But I can see how reasonable people could differ on that, *and* it's a not a necessary part of the answer (just commentary on process), so removing that part of my answer does make it better. Thanks.

Answer (score 32):

It's trivia.  It doesn't belong anywhere on the network.

Here's the red flag:

> What notable electronic systems are in use 2015, which do not use a CPU or other programmable part?

Does it *matter* in 2016?  Will the question have to be revised in 2017?  How does this knowledge benefit anyone outside of someone playing the strangest computer trivia game?  Why would anyone care about this?

I don't see it having any value here, and I don't think there are any sites on the network that can objectively answer it.

Comment: You are correct, it does not matter whether it's 2014, 2015, or 2016. The answers likely would not be significantly different. However, I disagree that this makes it trivia. As to whether it can be objectively answered, I think so. It it quite feasible for one more answers to name qualifying systems that can be objectively verified. Now, there is no *single* answer, because the Q is attempting to compile a list, but that does mean that the answers would not be objective. That said, your view of it being of no value seems to be shared, so I wont ask it anywhere else on SE.

Comment: @tom: No, it's trivia. There's no relevance to creating a list of those devices (if any), and at the rate technology changes now any list created would likely be invalid or incomplete next week (and again the week after, ad nauseum). None of the SE sites are appropriate for this type of question for precisely that reason. If you think it will be so enlightening to engineers that it's a must have, find a non-SE engineering site and ask there.

Comment: Well, I suppose one man's trivia is another man's broad-based knowledge. Not sure what 'relevance' you're referring to. Is there no topic in the world to which this is relevant, or just the SO topics? Seems that a 16 year-old aspiring engineer might be interested to know how the world around him works, and what subjects he might pursue to contribute to it (CS? EE? both? - do traffic lights run code?). I was that 16 year-old nearly 20 years ago.. my... a lot has changed since then!

Comment: @tom: Then that *16-year old aspiring engineer* can find it on another non-SE engineering site where that type of question is appropriate. I really don't understand people who ask a question and then decide to argue every single response they get. If you don't want to listen to the answer, why bother to ask the question in the first place? SO (and SE in general) has guidelines for topics for specific reasons. They exist because the vast majority of users have decided they're appropriate. Your question does not fit within those guidelines.

Comment: (continued) And with regard to your asking it on SO in the first place, it's **clearly** off topic there, as your question is a) not even remotely programming related, and b) clearly asks about devices that are **not programmed**, which removes them from any relevance on SO whatsoever.

Comment: @Ken White some missing context: I posted my answer (which fully accepts that it doesn't belong anywhere on SE) before my last comment to you. So I absolutely am "listening to the answer". The reason I'm " arguing this point " is that the word "trivia" is pejorative and subjective. So I disagree with that specific part, despite agreeing with you on the overall answer. Seems to me that with the rules being as clear as there, there's no benefit to such subjectivity.

Comment: _"the word 'trivia' is pejorative and subjective"_ Wrong on both counts.

Comment: **trivia:** *details, considerations, or pieces of information of little importance or value.*

Answer (score 13):

As [Paebbels notes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309601/where-best-to-ask-this-question-on-se-if-at-all#309603), the *subject matter* of this question would be a pretty spot-on fit for [Electrical Engineering](http://electronics.stackexchange.com).

That said, as [Nick Alexeev comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309601/where-best-to-ask-this-question-on-se-if-at-all#comment267738_309603) just below, the question *as written* would also be quickly closed on *any* SE site, because it's a [list question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124450/what-is-the-definition-of-a-list-question) and such questions [don't work well on SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98334/list-questions-community-wiki).

It *might* be possible to turn this into a reasonable SE question, but it'd require an all but complete rewrite.  Basically, you'd need to get rid of the Big List aspect entirely, and instead focus on *what it is that you want to learn from this*.  A possible starting point would be the last paragraph in your original question, where you do explain some of your motivations for asking it:

> As background: it's common knowledge that CPUs are finding their way into more and more systems. What's unknown to me is whether there a places that isn't happening, either due to legacy installations, or even more interestingly, design choices.

OK, *that* looks like it might be (the seed of) an answerable SE question.  Let me tidy it up a bit:

> #### Are there still electronic devices that don't use a CPU?
>
> It's common knowledge that CPUs, microcontrollers and other similar programmable devices are finding their way into more and more systems.  Are there any particular places where that isn't happening, either due to legacy installations, or even more interestingly, design choices?

That's starting to look like something that *might* survive on EE.SE.  It's still kind of broad (there surely are *plenty* of such examples, if you know the subject), but one *could* presumably write a reasonable answer to it.  If you're still curious about this, I'd suggest asking *something like* that on the appropriate site, and seeing what happens.  Worst case, it'll be closed again; best case, you'll get a good answer.

You might want to check that it's not a duplicate first, though.

Answer (score -10):

It's a Electrical Engineering question, because Hardware Software Codesign should be on-topic at [EE.SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: That SO question would have lasted for about 3 minutes on EE.SE before it got closed.  It lacks a lot of thinking or research.  In other words, it's a lazy question.

Comment: @NickAlexeev I suggest that in order to substantiate your claim of 'lack of research', 'lack of thinking', and 'lazy' you include some specific examples. I.e. what research, what thinking. Without those, your comment seems subjective, and judgmental. If you think it can be improved to the point where it can be asked on EE.SE, please suggest how.

Comment: @tom It's *your* responsibility to do your due diligence in what the standards are for a question on a site you want to post a question on.  Others are welcome to give you tips if they want, but it's *your* responsibility at the end of the day, as it's your question.

Comment: @Servy I agree, it's my responsibility. But I don't know which 'thinking and research' is missing, so I'm asking for help. It seemed like NickAlexeev might be able to help (because he said they were missing), so I asked. I also said that w/o that detail, his comment seems judgmental, which I stand by.

Comment: @tom if you want clarity on that point, you might have said, for example, "@NickAlexeev what specific research would you expect to see to make it a good question for EE.SE?" - ie, *ask* for clarity rather than demand it. Suggesting that a comment "seems subjective and judgmental", well, seems subjective and judgmental, and doesn't help anyone (especially when the comment is made by a diamond moderator of EE.SE, whose subjective opinions on what is a good question there *do* carry weight and *can* be assumed to be based on in-depth experience of that community's standards).